# How to get a random row that contains certain text in a postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am quite new to sql, I am using postgresql if a have a table `my_table`

```
 id |   name
----+----------
```

How could I get a random row that contains a certain text.

I have this so far, to choose a random row:

```sql
select * from my_table offset random() * (select count(*) from my_table) limit 5;
```

How would I modify this to only choose from rows with name like whatever, or is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not guaranteed to return 5 random rows -- or even 5 rows at all because the offset could be near the end of the data.  If the table is not very large or if there are relatively few matches for the `where` clause, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where name like ?
order by random()
limit 5;
```

With larger tables, the performance impact depends on how many rows match the `where` conditions and whether the `where` conditions can be satisfied using an index.  The performance is determined by the number of rows that need to be sorted.